# Simplifying Circuits

Tags: logic, computer-science

[image]

I have a question regarding simplifying a circuit of a function below that has 5 logic gates in original.

$f = (A + B) \cdot (C + D) + (A + B) \cdot (C + D)' + C$

$= (A + B) \cdot ((C + D) + (C + D)') + C$

$= (A + B) \cdot 1 + \overline{C} \quad$  ($\overline{C}$ denotes the complement of $C$)

$= (A + B) + C$

Now, I have reduced to $2$ logic gates from $5$. But, here, am I allowed to change $(A + B) + C$ to $A + B + C$, so that I can reduce number of gates (i.e., $1$ logic gate) even more? If I am allowed, is there a name for this process (what kind of law is this)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for [Electrical Engineering StackExchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  Try asking it there with the tag *logic-gates*

Comment: Now asked at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/151648/8090

Comment: So long as $C$ is not a constant $0$ or $1$, I don't see how you can have only $1$ gate to realize that Boolean operation

Comment: I think the OP is thinking of a $3$-input gate.  A $3$-input OR gate was implied in the first line.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören, take a look at the EESE version, the OP has included a drawing showing a $3$-input gate.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I heard that with a bracket, as in (A+B)+C, I need to separate A+B and C with 2-input gates for each. So, if I could just omit brackets, I could have 3-input gate covering A+B+C.

Comment: It is *associativity* : see **Associativity of** $\lor$ in [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, actually, the expression in the Wikipedia page still uses two 2-input logic gates, that is, the parentheses are still there.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche - yes, but it is the same as *addition* between natural numbers : if $(2+1)+1=2+(1+1)$, then we can simply omit the parentheses and write : $2+1+1$ and the result does not change. This applies to circuits, provide that a 3-inputs OR-gate is defined as a gate that outputs FALSE only when all three inputs are FALSE.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You have correctly simplified the circuit by using in turn: (1) distribution, (2) disjunction of complements, (3) conjunction's identity.

Finally, you can say $\;(A+B)+C = A+B+C\;$ because of the *associativity of disjunction*.

Thus you have pared it down to just one logic gate, a triple-or gate (such as the one used in the original diagram),